# How are FIDE rating changes calculated for a tournament across rating periods?

Tags: fide, rating

If I play a FIDE-rated tournament with games from the April 30th to May 2nd, will the ELO changes be calculated using my April rating, my May rating, or April in April and May in May?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rating is calculated using all his results [as if they were played with your starting rating](https://qc.fide.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Rating-Regulations-Change-Sheet.docx).